# SPUtility.SendEmail() always returns false

Tags: 2010, email, sputility

I have one application which will create task form for each level based on the prior level approval. While creating each tasks I have to send the email to the users who all are involved in the task. For this I am using SPUtility.SendEmail() method. But unfortunately, it didn't work so far. The debugger successfully passed through the SendEmail method without any exception. but the value will always false. The SMTP server is working for the application other than the SP Applications. My code is shown below.

```
  SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                using (SPSite spSite = new SPSite(SiteURL))
                {
                    using (SPWeb spWeb = spSite.OpenWeb())
                    {
                        headers = new StringDictionary();
                        headers.Add("to", To);
                        headers.Add("from", From);
                        headers.Add("cc", CC);
                        headers.Add("bcc", BCC);
                        if (Priority.Equals("High"))
                        {
                            headers.Add("X-Priority", "1 (Highest)");
                            headers.Add("X-MSMail-Priority", "High");
                            headers.Add("Importance", "High");
                        }
                        headers.Add("subject", Subject);
                        headers.Add("content-type", "text/html");
                        Status= SPUtility.SendEmail(spWeb, headers, Body);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Please help me to resolve this issue. All Suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work without your "special" headers, with just subject left?

Comment: @RobertLindgren: No. It didn't work..

Comment: And SharePoint outgoing email is configured and working?

Comment: @RobertLindgren: Yes, everything except this SPUtility Send Email are working.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a `StringDictionary()` but not using the overload of `SPUtility.SendEmail` which uses `StringDictionary` as one of the parameters `SPUtility.SendEmail Method (SPWeb, StringDictionary, String)`

Comment: I was used the StringDictionary. For the testing purpose I have changed the code today itself. Please check my code now.

Answer (score 0):

We struggled with same issue. What we realized that `SPUtility.SendEmail` did not work when it was written inside `SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges`. I couldn't find any specific reason for this. As a workaround we used `MailMessage` to send email.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(<mailFrom>, <recipientMail>);
message.Subject = "<Subject>";
message.Body = "<BODY>";
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(<mailServer>, <mailPort>);
smtp.Send(message);
```